# What is faster? Find in object or in array

Tags: javascript

Which of these 2 functions in javascript is faster?
Key is ObjectId from mongodb.

First - data is object indexed by ID key:

```
function itemExists ( id, data ) {

  // data is object indexed by ids
  return ( id in data );
}
```

Second - data is array of objects with ID key inside:

```
function itemExists2 ( id, data ) {

  // data is array of object
  for ( var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++ ) {

    if ( data[i].id == id )
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your code. Which do you think is faster? :p That said, `data.hasOwnProperty(id)` may be most reliable.

Comment: [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/) it yourself

Comment: [This](http://jsperf.com/fast-array-foreach/35)

Comment: just do a runtime analysis....how long does it take to write a loop and time compare

Comment: I don't know - it's about internal features that JavaScript uses to manage objects

Comment: My guess is that it would depend on browser implementation/version.

Comment: Have you link, which would describe how is it processed in JavaScript? I focus mainly on V8 engine.